# Mysql - How To Count I'ds that are in table for every day to the fullest?

Tags: mysql, date, count, distinct

```
SELECT DATE(At), count(*)
FROM purchases
GROUP BY DATE(At)
```

this query is not good because some customers come to my store in many different ways.
like 4 time in day and then at the next day they will not come at all. this costumers should be out of the count. i need only customers who appears every single day, even more than on time a day.

my data is:

-

### - At---------------------------   Ids

### 2013-12-15 12:00:00 ----100000000052178

### 2013-12-15 16:00:00 -----10000000009478

### 2013-12-15 15:42:00 -----10000000014101

### 2013-12-14 10:00:00 -----10000000009478

### 2013-12-14 22:00:00 -----100000000176651

### 2013-12-13 12:36:00 -----100000000192714

### 2013-12-13 12:23:56-----10000000009478

-RESULT:

### Month -------------- Count

### 12-2013 -------------45

### 11-2013 ------------59

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Date is long: '2013-12-15 23:59:59'

Comment: date should be Month. customers should be numbers

Comment: Please add more. A little table of example data and a table of the result. All in your question.

Comment: So basically you want a query which displays every month of the year with the number of customers who have visited your store at least once on every single day of the given month?

Comment: YES, Month Or Period. in addition I will love to get this Id's too' but i think i will be able to take it from the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

try something like below query.

```
SELECT date_format(At,'%M%Y') as At, COUNT(ids) as ids FROM table_name  GROUP BY month(At)
```